# Two Fedora 23 Installation On The Same Computer

Tags: fedora, luks

Currently I am trying to install two fedora 23 operating systems, on my single computer.

Now the issue is that when I try to install the second Fedora 23 OS everything is fine till the time it tries to install the bootloader, it fails then.
I googled around and read that there is a conflict in the grub2.

Also I am encrypting the disks with LUKS.

I have also tried not to install the bootloader for one of the operating system, but that did not work, as since the disks are encrypted grub2 was not able to detect the other Fedora 23 OS

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I don't think this is a configuration we support. Can you explain you use case?

Comment: @mattdm I'm thinking use case might be: "one for work, one for play", in which case I'd recommend using a VM for the less used one (Gnome boxes or Virt-manager). /speculation